Ubuntu 22.04 Set up net plan with multiple network interfaces only works with both default routes
I'm setting up a server with 2 network interfaces, I want the main network interface to be the default one to be used, and only use the other for 3 very specific subnets.
However, when I configure the netplan, I'm unable to ping the server from those 3 subnets without setting a to: default route on both interfaces, which obviously makes no sense.
My desired config
network:
version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.8.13/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [172.16.6.244, 172.16.6.245]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 172.16.8.254
    enp11s0:
      addresses:
        - 10.129.81.215/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.22.73.161, 10.22.73.33]
      routes:
        - to: 10.146.0.0/16
          via: 10.129.81.10
        - to: 10.230.0.0/16
          via: 10.129.81.10
        - to: 10.138.0.0/16
          via: 10.129.81.10

This one gives me the ability to ping the server from a 10.146.x.x device
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.8.13/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [172.16.6.244, 172.16.6.245]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 172.16.8.254
    enp11s0:
      addresses:
        - 10.129.81.215/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.22.73.161, 10.22.73.33]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.129.81.10
        - to: 10.146.0.0/16
          via: 10.129.81.10
        - to: 10.230.0.0/16
          via: 10.129.81.10
        - to: 10.138.0.0/16
          via: 10.129.81.10

But this configuration gives warnings because there are 2 default routes, which makes sense of course.
Using this config causes the server to ONLY reply on the 172.16.8.0 subnet, but not on 172.16.2.0 for example.
How do I properly set up a routing table like this in Ubuntu? I'm used to CentOS, but the network interface files don't seem to exist in Ubuntu.
I'm trying to find the equivalent in Ubuntu for the following commands in Windows to add permanent routes:
route -p ADD 10.146.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.129.81.10 metric 30
route -p ADD 10.230.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.129.81.10 metric 30
route -p ADD 10.138.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.129.81.10 metric 30

ip ro s output
default via 172.16.8.254 dev ens160 proto static
10.129.81.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.129.81.215
10.138.0.0/16 via 10.129.81.10 dev ens192 proto static
10.146.0.0/16 via 10.129.81.10 dev ens192 proto static
10.230.0.0/16 via 10.129.81.10 dev ens192 proto static
172.16.8.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.8.13


Your IP allocation looks odd, as 10.138.0.0/12 is actually 10.128.0.0/12 subnet; could you please update your question with the output of ip ro s in both cases?

No that's not what it is supposed to be. This is the equivalent in windows:
route -p ADD 10.146.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.129.81.10 metric 30
route -p ADD 10.230.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.129.81.10 metric 30
route -p ADD 10.138.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.129.81.10 metric 30

Well, 255.255.0.0 mask is 16 bits, not 12, so instead of /12 in netplan you should use /16. Please update your question with the output of ip ro s in both cases anyway.

OMG, I feel like such a dunce, how did I keep reading over that. After adjusting the mask bitcount it just works as intended. The routes now also show up in the ip ro s, whilst they didn't before. Anyway, thank you very much. Not sure if I should keep this question online now. Maybe I should rewrite it for educational purposes. There isn't much info to find on having multi network interface configs in Ubuntu.

The original question used incorrect subnet specifications, i.e. 10.138.0.0/12 that is actually 10.128.0.0/12, but netplan seems to silently ignore incorrect route prefixes in routes: stanza; no warnings about that matter are generated by netplan try and netplan apply commands.
As usual, using ip route show to verify that routes are (or not) installed for the prefix in question provides a hint to the above.
